# Attempting to generate javadoc in Eclipse but getting "Error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm working on an assignment and having trouble generating a javadoc html file for this class I've made. I've clicked Project > Generate Java Doc > Javadoc command auto filled to C:\Users\Evanl\workspace\CSC - Car Class\bin\Main\Car.class > click Next > name the document "Car javadoc" > click FInish and get error [Error 193](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl8kj.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Main that runs my program:

```
package Main;

public class CarMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car("Honda", "Civic", "Black", 2020);

        System.out.println(car1.toString() +"\n"+car1.ageOfCar()+"\n");

        // TODO (Optional)
        // Create another Car object named car2 and input your own values :)
        // And then output its values like I did in line 5
        // This is completely optional
        
        Car myCar = new Car("Jeep", "Wrangler", "Black", 2023);
        System.out.println(myCar.toString() +"\n"+myCar.ageOfCar()+"\n");
    }
}
```

Car class:

```
package Main;

/**
 * @author Evan Cammack
 * @version 1.0
 * created on 2/15/2023
 * this is a template for a software car object
*/
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Car {


  //private fields
  private String make;
  private String model;
  private String color;
  private int year;
  private double mileage;

  //default constructor sets all fields to default blank values
  public Car(){
    make = "";
    model = "";
    color = "";
    year = 0;
    mileage = 0;
  }
 
  //custom constructor
  //"this" refers to current object

  /**
   * @param make String parameter representing make of car
   * @param model String parameter representing model of car
   * @param color String parameter representing color of car
   * @param year int parameter representing year of car
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if year equals "0000"
  */

  public Car(String make, String model, String color, int year){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    if (year <= 0000)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.year = year;
    mileage = 0;
  }

  //getters
  /**
   * @return make - the make of the car
  */
  public String getMake(){
    return this.make;
  }
  /**
   * @return model - the model of the car
  */
  public String getModel(){
    return this.model;
  }
  /**
   * @return color - the color of the car
  */
  public String getColor(){
    return this.color;
  }
  /**
   * @return year - the year of the car
  */
  public int getYear(){
    return this.year;
  }

  //setters
  /**
   * @param make changes to the make of the car to given input String
  */
  public void setMake(String make){
    this.make = make;
  }
  /**
   * @param make changes to the model of the car to given input String
  */
  public void setModel(String model){
    this.model = model;
  }
  /**
   * @param make changes to the color of the car to given input String
  */
  public void setColor(String color){
    this.color = color;
  }
  /**
   * @param make changes to the year of the car to given input String
  */
  public void setYear(int year){
    this.year = year;
  }

  /**
   * @return ageOfCar - how old the car is
   */
  public String ageOfCar() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int ageOfCar = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - this.year;
    return "This car is "+ageOfCar+" years old.";
  }
  
  /**
   * @return make, model, color, year - returns make, model, color, and year in a string
   */
  public String toString() {
    return "Make: " +this.make+" Model: "+this.model+" Color: "+this.color+" Year: "+this.year;
  }
  
}
```

I've tried googling and youtubing this specific error message but there's no guides to help fix it.

Comment: The Javadoc command is not correct. On Windows, it it has to be like `<JDK_HOME>\bin\javadoc.exe` (replace `<JDK_HOME>` with the installation directory of the JDK you want to use).